# JQuery animate list items in sequence then fade out list and repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a sequence of events that I am trying to create using jQuery but I am failing miserably.

I have a number of lists with a number of list items in each list. The list of events I am trying to achieve is as follows:

Fade in list 1 > Animate List 1 item 1 > Animate List 1 item 2 etc...
Fade out list 1
Fade in list 2 > Animate List 2 item 1 > Animate List 2 item 2 etc...
Fade out list 2 etc...

This would then loop over and over.

My current jQuery is as follows:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay((i++) * 2000).animate({left:0, opacity:1});
    });
});
```

I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zp240znv/ outlining how far I have gotten with this but it is woefully lacking so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is this your desired effect? http://jsfiddle.net/zp240znv/3/

Comment: @wiesion it's a bit tricky, but it's short and correct one. You should probably post it as an answer...

Comment: there's just one problem with my quick fix, it delays 2000ms after the first element of the next list is displayed, are you ok with that?

Comment: i've posted an answer containing both versions (code and link to fiddle)

Comment: Wow, wonderful response, thank you :) I'll look through them and accept an answer asap. Thanks

Comment: This is a very nice snipet, works very fine for me tanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create recursive functions. One function could iterate through the parent lists, while the second will iterate through each item in each list:

```
function AnimateList($listItems, index, callback) {
    if (index >= $listItems.length) {
        $listItems.closest("ul").fadeOut(function() {
            $listItems.css("left","400px").css("opacity",0); //reset
            callback(); //next list
        });
        return;
    }

    $listItems.eq(index).animate({left:0, opacity:1}, function() {
        AnimateList($listItems, index+1, callback)
    });
}

function FadeLists($lists, index) {
    if (index >= $lists.length) index = 0;

    var $currentList = $lists.eq(index);
    $currentList.fadeIn(function() {
        AnimateList($currentList.find("li"), 0, function() { FadeLists($lists, index + 1) });
    }) 
}

var $allLists = $("ul")
FadeLists($allLists, 0);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zp240znv/16/

Comment: This is great, thank you. I have changed it slightly to slow it down a bit but that you so much for this :)

Answer (score 4):

As requested by @Regent, posting my answer along with an updated fiddle which removes also the delay when showing the second item of the >0 index lists.

OLD FIDDLE (with delay between hiding previous list and showing 2nd element)

```
var i = 0;
$('ul').each(function() {
    var hide_after = $(this).children().length;
    $(this).children().each(function(counter) {
        $(this)
            .delay(++i * 2000)
            .animate({left:0, opacity:1})
            .delay((hide_after - counter) * 2000)
            .animate({left:'100%', opacity: 0});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zp240znv/3/

NEW FIDDLE using timeOuts (correct way without overdoing it with coding)

```
var base_duration = 2000;
$('ul').each(function(i) {
    var li_count = $(this).children().length,
        hide_timeout = ((i+1) * base_duration * li_count);
    $(this).children().each(function(ii) {
        var li = $(this),
            show_timeout = (i * li_count * base_duration) + (ii * base_duration);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            li.animate({left:0, opacity:1})
        }, show_timeout);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            li.animate({left:'100%', opacity:0})
        }, hide_timeout);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zp240znv/17/

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's the code

```
<ul id="first">
                <li>List 1, Line 1</li>
                <li>List 1, Line 2</li>
                <li>List 1, Line 3</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="second">
                <li>List 2, Line 1</li>
                <li>List 2, Line 2</li>
                <li>List 2, Line 3</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="third">
                <li>List 2, Line 1</li>
                <li>List 2, Line 2</li>
                <li>List 2, Line 3</li>
            </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#first").fadeIn(300,function(){
            $(this).children().each(function(i) {
               $(this).delay((i++) * 2000).animate({left:0, opacity:1});
           });

        });

        setTimeout(function(){
        second_animate();
        },5000)

        function second_animate(){
            $('#first').fadeOut(300,function(){
                $("#second").fadeIn(300,function(){
            $(this).children().each(function(i) {
               $(this).delay((i++) * 2000).animate({left:0, opacity:1});
           });

        });
            });
        }

        </script>
```

Check fiddle you have posted i have edited that

Comment: Please post all your code here. Link only answers are not answers!

Comment: Can you rewrite code so that it does not depend on `<ul>` count? Also you should post code as part of answer, not just a link to fiddle.

Comment: @Spokey now I'm late for 2 seconds :)

Comment: @Spokey i dont know in which basis the user wants the answer i had edited his fiddle thats it :) and i can also do without ul count if you insist

Comment: Yeah I understand but while this answer is for the user, many other people will see it and Stackoverflow rules suggest that you have to put the code in your answer. Also if it's nicely done and well formatted you'll get upvotes :). @Regent you're catching up. Maybe next time you'll be first :P

Answer (score -1):

```
$( ".first" ).animate({ "left": "+=5px" }, 500,function(){
  $( ".second" ).animate({ "left": "+=5px" }, 500,function(){
    $( ".third" ).animate({ "left": "+=5px" }, 500,function(){
      $( "#mainContainer" ).hide("slow"); //main container of all that div 
    });
  });
});
```

At the place of left animation you can place your  and here main container is which contains that all divs. hope your problem is solved

```
$('#firstulid').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).animate({left:0, opacity:1},2000, function(){
              $('#firstulid').hide("slow");
              $('#secondulid').each(function() {
              $(this).children().each(function(i) {
                  $(this).animate({left:0, opacity:1},2000, function(){
                                 $('#secondulid').hide("slow");
                                 $('#thirdulid').each(function() {
                                    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
                                        $(this).animate({left:0, opacity:1},2000, function(){

                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                  });
              });
          });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where did you find `.first`, `.second`, `.third` and `#mainContainer`? Also, if there will be 100 `<ul>`s - will you write code in this style?

Comment: no you can make it dynamically, it is for few div's only but is also a good solution and easy for beginners

Comment: I think this is a poor approach because it doesn't address an infinite/indefinite number of items. Don't teach beginners to think in a limited fashion.