# How to make this animation repeat itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

This animation is working exactly how I want it to, but I'm a JS/jQuery newbie and am unsure how to loop my animation so it continues infinitely. Here is a link to a CodePen as well. Thanks in advance! https://codepen.io/summeropratt/pen/qBbVdpQ

**HTML**

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="seven-flex-grid">
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col child-seven">
          <img draggable="false" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_location_on_48px-512.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.body{
  max-width: 600px !important;
}
.seven-flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 108rem;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0px 24px;
  width: 20px;
}
.col img {
  width: 100%;
}
.child-seven {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var points = $(".child-seven");
    var queue = $.Deferred().resolve(); // create an empty queue
    points.get().forEach(function(li){
        queue = queue.then(function(){
           return $(li).animate({opacity: 100}, 1000).promise();
        })
    });
 });
```

Comment: Look into CSS Keyframes. Although jQuery and Vanilla JavaScript are perfectly able to do animations, they are not as good as CSS is. And imo is much easier to work with.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788466/jquery-animate-list-items-in-sequence-then-fade-out-list-and-repeat

Comment: When the loop happens, should all items go back to `opacity: 0` and then start revealing again? Or should they then animate back to 0 in a list?

Answer (score 0):

Make infinite loop using CSS keyframe and jQuery toggle class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function(){ 
     // toggle class every 4 sec, total 1 loop + 500ms
     $('.seven-flex-grid').toggleClass('animating');  
     setTimeout(function(){
       // toggle class every 3.5 sec, 7 icon * 500ms
       $('.seven-flex-grid').toggleClass('animating');  
     },3500);

  },4000);

});
```

CodePen link https://codepen.io/azhkuro/pen/GRoOqoq